# Attaching mouseover event to SVG rect collection using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, svg

I have an SVG drawing that represents a floor plan and am attempting to attach mouseover events to a rect collection that are in g tags in the SVG code.

For a particular SVG g tag, I have something like this:

```
    <g id="f3s362c12">
      <g>
         <rect x="75.2" y="92.4" fill="none" width="64.7" height="57.8" />
         <polyline fill="none" stroke="#CDDDED" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="118.4,149.9 140.3,149.9 140.3,92.4 
        75.2,92.4 75.2,128.7        " />
      </g>
      <g>
         <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 87.8719 144.8836)" fill="#010101" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="13.4182">362.12</text>
  </g>
 </g>
```

And in my jQuery, I am finding all  elements that start with id=f3:

```
var gElements = $("[id^='f3']");
```

Then, I create collection of rect elements from gElements:

```
var rectColl = gElements.find('rect');
```

At this point, I thought that I could iterate through the rectColl collection and attach a mouseover event, however, this doesn't appear to be the case:

```
for (i = 0; i < rectColl.length; i++) {
  $(rectColl[i]).mouseover(function() {
  //$(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
  alert('hello');
 });
}
```

Any idea of where I am going astray?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drdexter33/vg5gkk38/6/)

Thanks.

doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `fill` attribute set to `none`. `none` value for the fill attribute, will disable the mouse events. You cange it to `transparent`:

```
<rect x="140.3" y="92.4" fill="none" width="68.8" height="57.8" />
```

to

```
<rect x="140.3" y="92.4" fill="transparent" width="68.8" height="57.8" />
```

or you can add the `pointer-events="visible"` to the rect in order to have mouse events with a `none` `fill` like this:

```
<rect x="75.2" y="92.4" pointer-events="visible" fill="none" width="64.7" height="57.8" />
```

```js
jQuery(function($){
    $("[id^='f3'] rect").on('mousemove', function() {
        console.log('mousemove');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
    <g id="background">
      <rect x="1.5" y="0.3" fill="#5A8CC9" width="298.7" height="300.4" />
    </g>
    <g id="f3s362c12">
      <g>
        <rect x="75.2" y="92.4" pointer-events="visible" fill="none" width="64.7" height="57.8" />
        <polyline fill="none" stroke="#CDDDED" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="118.4,149.9 140.3,149.9 140.3,92.4 
            75.2,92.4 75.2,128.7        " />
      </g>
      <g>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 87.8719 144.8836)" fill="#010101" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="13.4182">362.12</text>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="f3s362c11">
      <g>
        <rect x="75.2" y="149.9" fill="transparent" width="64.7" height="57.8" />
        <polyline fill="none" stroke="#CDDDED" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="118.4,207.8 140.3,207.8 140.3,149.9 
            75.2,149.9 75.2,186.2       " />
      </g>
      <g>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 87.8719 201.6532)" fill="#010101" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="13.4182">362.11</text>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="f3s362c2">
      <g>
        <rect x="140.3" y="149.9" fill="none" width="68.8" height="57.8" />
        <polyline fill="none" stroke="#CDDDED" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="208.7,183.5 208.7,149.9 140.3,149.9 
            140.3,207.8 185.8,207.8         " />
      </g>
      <g>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 163.782 201.6532)" fill="#010101" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="13.4182">362.2</text>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="f3s362c1">
      <g>
        <rect x="140.3" y="92.4" fill="none" width="68.8" height="57.8" />
        <polyline fill="none" stroke="#CDDDED" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="208.7,126 208.7,92.4 140.3,92.4 
            140.3,149.9 185.8,149.9         " />
      </g>
      <g>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 163.782 144.8836)" fill="#010101" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="13.4182">362.1</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for this.
I have very little experience working with SVG and JQuery, however I am trying to produce something similar to the NYT election response map from the last election here in the US: http://www.nytimes.com/elections/results/president
Or something at least on a smaller scale.

Comment: Oh! Don't waste your time and make your own solution! Look here https://datamaps.github.io/. It even has a US map example (3rd map) with all the states and sample popup boxes. That is exactly what you need. You just have to check the example and the documentation on how to integrate it, change colors and have your own text inside popup boxes on states hover event.